# Threading Shimano chain, over or under lug?

Tags: chain, shimano, derailleur-rear, replacement

I have an MTB with Shimano Deore/SLX components.

I just replaced the chain.

Should the chain go over the lug as I have it in the picture?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you are calling the lug

Comment: There is a little bit of metal between the jockey wheels.

Comment: I don't see it. Could you maybe edit the image to add an arrow pointing to it or something similar? (Perhaps Adam's answer has already told you everything you need to know, but it would be helpful to future visitors to the site if your question was clearer.)

Comment: Done , the bike is upside down in the photo by the way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Shimano seems to keep a lot of their documentation [online](http://si.shimano.com/), you can find your specific manual there.

For example, the site gives this picture for DEORE XT RD-M8000 derailleur.

[image: rear derailleur chain routing]

Essentially, the chain needs to follow the shortest path between the two jockey wheels.  When installed properly, the chain won't touch the plate at all.  If it does you've routed it incorrectly.  But it appears from your pictures that it's routed incorrectly, the chain appears to be held off of the upper (lower in the photo) jockey wheel more than I'd expect.

Comment: Thanks for that I think the images are deceiving as the bike is upside down and I am pullling the chain so you can see it.

Comment: I had it setup correctly.

Comment: Basically, when the chain is taut on the jockey wheels it should not be rubbing on anything else.

Comment: @LeBlaireau as Ross mentions in his answer, the photos show a chain that is routed incorrectly. so it's weird that you've commented you had it set up correctly, maybe that was a typo. 2 years later, it's probably worn through the plate if it was wrong, therefore it's a bit of a moot point

Answer (score 3):

It's difficult to make out in this picture, but I believe the keeper bar on the cage should be forward of the chain.

The way to determine whether the chain is threaded correctly is to see whether it drags on the keeper bar when it moves. If it drags, it's threaded wrong.

Comment: New pics added.

Answer (score 1):

The pictures definitely show a chain that is routed incorrectly on the wrong side of the derailment prevention plate. (See diagram) It doesn’t matter that the bike is upside down, the chain is clearly on the wrong side of the plate.

Comment: Welcome to the bikes SE! You're correct that the OP had routed the chain wrongly. However, this site works differently from most internet forums. There was already an accepted answer that stated this. Attempts to answer old questions are welcomed if they offer new information (I've done this many times!), but this answer doesn't appear to offer anything new.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site - you are totally correct in your observations, same as the other answers ~3 years ago.  So instead of adding another superfluous and redundant answer, just upvote the answers that are right, good, or helpful.    Do feel free to have a go at some of the other questions, either the harder unanswered ones, or the newest ones.   The "identify my bike" ones tend to be very hard.   Also have a browse through the [tour] to see how things work generally on Stackexchange.