# Why does my Shimano Deore SLX dérailleur not rotate into the expected (vertical) position?

Tags: mountain-bike, chain, derailleur, derailleur-rear

I have a Scott E-Genius 730 Plus mountain bike (around three years old). I had a chain snap recently, so I have replaced the rear 10-speed cassette, and am now trying to route a new chain correctly. I have removed a few links, as the chain comes with 116 links and I think I only need 112, and I've added a quick link.

However, I am struggling to visualise how to put the chain back on, and I'm tempted to think there is an issue with the dérailleur. I've seen [the pictures in this question](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/50489/threading-shimano-chain-over-or-under-lug) but I can't make head or tail of them.

Here is a general image of my bike taken from the internet. You can see that the chain travels from the top of the crank pinion, over the top of the cassette on the rear wheel, loops around the upper dérailleur cog on the right hand side, then loops around the lower pinion, before travelling back to the crank.

[image: Shop picture of an E-Genius 730]

A key thing here is that the centre of the cassette, and the two dérailleur cogs should roughly be on the same vertical line, as per the image. I have another MTB (a KTM Action Macina) also with Shimano gear components, and this confirms that there is an approximate vertical alignment between these three gear pieces:

[image: KTM dérailleur with superimposed graphics]

However, my Scott is not like that. The cassette and the top pinion seem to be in vertical alignment, but the arm movement of the dérailleur mechanism would currently have to rotate some 90° anticlockwise in order to produce the same shape. I appreciate the problematic unit is not under spring/chain tension, and good examples of correct working order *are* under tension, but that is not the issue - the dérailleur *just won't go* into that shape. I cannot apply any more hand force onto the bottom section (i.e. rotating the blue bar anticlockwise) without breaking it.

[image: Scott dérailleur with superimposed graphics]

Here is an image of the Scott gear system without the superimposed graphics:

[image: Scott gears]

I am 99% sure that the dérailleur is not bent and was not modified or adjusted since the chain snap, and it was working fine previously (other than clanking a lot, due to poor chain condition). Of course, this position means that the chain is too short, especially now I have taken some links out of it.

Has my dérailleur slipped into an incorrect position, or have I made an error with my chain routing that needs correcting? My Scott has a chain-bounce switch, but either position does not help rotate the bottom section to a near-vertical orientation.

Comment: Welcome to bicycles. The text is nice and clear, but the photos would be clearer in full colour and without the big red blobs on, might be worth editing back to normal

Comment: Thanks @Swifty. The blobs are just to indicate the positions of the cogs, but yes, I can add the originals. I will do that shortly.

Comment: Yeah, I would swap them out. If someone knows about derailleurs enough to answer, they will know which way things should be. The words are descriptive to help too

Comment: Looks to me like the chain is too long.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: thanks, but the problem with the dérailleur is evident even with the chain removed. The marked section has some 5° of permitted rotary movement - almost as if something internally is locking it up - and I think that is wrong. My sense is that if I can fix this problem, I can then move onto whether the chain is the right size.

Comment: (FWIW, the old chain has 112 or 113 links, so I think my replacement chain is fine).

Comment: There are a dozen different ways to screw up mounting a derailer.  Without being there and twisting the derailer around it's hard to guess what the particular problem is.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: I should emphasise that I do not believe I have changed the position of the dérailleur, and the odds of it being knocked and me not knowing about it are, I think, fairly low. I am hesitant to remove it, to examine if something is preventing its normal rotation patterns, as I am not a confident gear tuner, and I am liable to make it worse. I am hoping to be able to leave it be, in the hope that once the immediate problem is resolved, it does not feed further adjustment.

Comment: Still looks to me like the chain is too long.  What happens if you simply pull on the chain, to cause the derailer to extend?

Comment: @DanielRHicks: the marked section of the dérailleur gives maybe 5° of anticlockwise movement, and then stops dead. I have removed the chain entirely and the same problem is exhibited. There do not appear to be any stops on the outside of the dérailleur frame that are inhibiting the expected rotary travel, so I wonder if there is something locking it up internally.

Comment: Which bolt are you trying to rotate around?  There is sometimes a little movement in the one to the right, but the one to the left is where most of the action is.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: I'm trying (currently by hand) to rotate the lower body of the dérailleur, not a bolt (the marked section in blue that connects the two pinions). I expect this to have around 90° of anticlockwise travel. In the Scott pictures it is essentially horizontal, and I believe that under chain tension, it should rotate to a nearly vertical position.

Comment: Yeah, that should rotate about 180 degrees.  I can't tell for sure, but it looks like you may have the chain routed on the wrong side of the pin in the in the middle of the arm, though I wouldn't expect that to affect the "swing" of the arm.

Comment: @DanielRHicks, indeed. Since the picture was taken I have removed the chain entirely, just to ensure the chain was not blocking rotary movement, and it is not. I could produce a small video to show the problem, in case there is a known problem with SLX dérailleurs, or a trick with the chain-slap device. [This article](https://www.bikeradar.com/features/how-to-adjust-a-shimano-shadow-plus-clutch-rear-derailleur/) indicates that one can remove the cover and adjust things inside - I did not know that! I wonder if I can get the top off without breaking something `:-)`.

Comment: The clutch mechanism would definitely be the first suspect. You do have it disengaged, right?

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus: thanks. I had tried both positions. Since I last posted I have found a solution, but I am minded to agree with you - I think the clutch is faulty.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: a solution has been found, which I have posted below. Thank you for your thoughts. I think I can fix it for now, but that I should try to track down a replacement rear dérailleur, in case the rotation resistance gets worse.

Answer (score 3):

The solution turned out to be very simple - after the first 5° of sweep, if I push *extremely* hard, to the degree I feel a breakage is inevitable, another ~175° is indeed available. The amount of torque required to burst past this apparent stop is enough to make a 20kg e-bike creak against the maintenance stand clamp! Interestingly if the anti-slap clutch is off, the sweep is even harder to make, and there is almost a scratchy, harsh resistance to the movement. I thought the clutch was meant to make it harder when it is On, not when it is Off, but mine is the other way around.

During my investigations, I tried to remove the fascia plate to examine the clutch. There are three hex bolts, arranged in a triangle formation; I removed two, and managed to wear away the hex key slot for the third, and I may need now to drill that out. I have decided not to investigate this further.

Given my findings, I was finally able to replace chain - I used a bungee cord to keep the dérailleur forward, so the quick link could be fitted. However it feels like it may be worth replacing the dérailleur unit entirely - the chain is now clanking in a way that it did not before, and it is under far too much tension. I wonder if the chain snap caused the dérailleur to fly back so violently that it has broken the clutch.

The dérailleur has RD-M7000 stamped in the metal casing, but a cursory search suggests there isn't much support left for 10 speeds. I will have a hunt about to see what I can find that will fit.

Comment: Its not todays way to get girls into bed and impress the jocks, so you won't see it in trendy coffee table magazines,  heaps of 10 Speed still used in the real world. Any decent sized shop will have 10 Speed parts on the shelf, otehrwise order in exactly what you want

Comment: 10 speed SLX does seem to be less available but 10 speed XT or 10 speed Deore will drop in just fine and trickle down tech means a 2020 Deore will be better than a 2016 SLX.

Comment: Ah right, thanks @WarrenBurton - that's useful to know. I will have another look with wider search parameters.

Comment: I'll roll with 10s XT (Model M786) all day. Use the m8020 front derailleur, which are dirt cheap, on my 2x10 (mixed generations play well together at the front drive only).  @mattnz Most frequently heard comment from bike chicks on my set-up: "Ohh, XT, baby. That's hot!" Despite the age, it still rocks.  Also, plenty of NOS, 10 speed, XTR parts (model #'s in the 900's) are available in the market at ok prices. Trickle down aside even tomorrow's Alivo will be hard pressed to perform like yesterday's XT or XTR, and it'll never have the "jena se qua," of the top dogs.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, more like a continuation of your question. It would be better to add a lot of what you wrote here it to your question. I think what are tryin ti convey as an answer is that your derailleur clutch is broken

Comment: @Argenti: I take the view that discovering the dérailleur arm was extremely stiff (and not actually locked) is essentially my answer. The reason why it got like that may be less important than the fact the unit probably is in need of replacement. I made a somewhat wordy answer to offer trouble-shooting ideas to future readers who have a similar problem, but I'll gladly accept an edit if you wish to make one.

Answer (score 2):

With the clutch engagement switch in the "off" position, the derailleur cage should move smoothly with the only resistance being from the cage spring. All indications are that your derailleur has failed (there's a good chance this is what caused your chain to break) and needs to be repaired or replaced. Pre-COVID, replacements for 10-speed XT RDs were not difficult to find. But failing that, Microshift's XLE 10-speed RD (RD-M625L) is a suitable Shimano compatible replacement. Arguably lower quality than XT, but it will get you riding again.