# Should the chain go inside or outside of the derailleur cage?

Tags: derailleur-rear

I see there is a lot of confusion about this. Should the chain be leaded through inside of the derailleur cage or outside? Example shown below is correct or not?

https://preview.redd.it/et0gzv72mop71.jpg?width=768&format=pjpg&auto=webp&s=23a8b3940820b0321c9aff6402cb844dc9d235c1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the video you linked the chain appears to be routed incorrectly. Here is the instruction:
[image]

The chain should should go from one jockey wheel to the other in a straight line, without bending over the cage pin.

Also your question is a duplicate of:
https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/50492/13579

Comment: Thank you. Many people are doing it wrong.

Comment: The wrong way should be recognized immediately. I did it twice and the noise is terrible, I cannot imagine leaving it like that.